# How to create an overlay that doesn't overflow its parent container?

Tags: css

I have 2 columns separated by 2 container.

In the first column I have set an element `<div class="overlay"></div>`
that should cover and overlay **ONLY** the first column.

I set the following css property on the class `overlay`.

```
.overlay {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
```

However, it doesn't just cover only the first column. It also cover the other second column.

I don't wanna set a fix width and fix height because I want to overlay the whole container. And I might run into issues soon if I do fix width.

Here is the [sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wxqtdhtb/) of what I have so far..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this CSS

```
.container-1{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wxqtdhtb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do with the overlay.  But you can try this code:

```
   .overlay {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
```

The relative position will force it to stay within the container.  The problem is that bc your overlay has nothing in it, it won't show up.

This is what I done to make it show up -> https://jsfiddle.net/908zodam/ (i just added a blank character in the overlay.)

Comment: basically I'm going to use the overlay to serve as a section blocker. Mujtaba answer works for me but thanks for the info :)